# Collapse Region VSCode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I want to fold the following lines of code in VSCode

```
x = np.linspace(0, 20, 100)
plt.plot(x, np.sin(x))
plt.show()
```

How do I do this? `ctrl + shift + [` only collapses functions.

Comment: You can use `#region` and `#endregion` to mark a region which can be folded: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/codebasics#_folding

Comment: Can I use folding without explecitily write #region #endregion ? so just any comment maybe #anything then I can make region?

Comment: @NurAfrizalBashri no, you must specify the markers, otherwise you're asking for the extension to just guess that you happen to think it's a region that should be foldable.

Answer (score 5):

you can try this free extension:
[Region Folding for VsCode](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=maptz.regionfolder)

Another way to do that in Native VScode is:

```
#region 
// your content here

#endregion
```

This block will make the arrow appear to collapse.

This is my favoryte way to do it:

```
#region ###########################  UPDATE #####################  
// your code here!


#endregion ###########################  END UPDATE #############
```

blessings !

Comment: is it also compatible with python?

Comment: Yes! it is compatible!

Comment: SImilar, see this SO question for a solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71991706/836330

Comment: In VSCode, I consider #region and #endregion to be better, and for other IDEs, we can use those specifications.